# Random sampling in python to save to df with indicator value

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python, and I am trying to do a random sampling in python 3, where I am trying to choose a random sampling based on which day it is,

the df has a bunch of different columns with date, user_id, telephone number etc. the index column is either a 0 or a 1, and I am trying to only random sample with those index values that are 0, and the last column labelled "keep" where all the data currently has a label of "no_include"

```
df.loc[(df.date <= '2019-01-02') & (df.date >= '2019-01-01')].loc[0].sample(n=100).replace(to_replace='no_include',value='include')
```

However, I want to do this random sampling with these, and for the replacement values to save, that way when I look at the whole dataset I can see which ones should have been randomly sampled, where the last column all the values are 'no_include,' I want to change 100 of those to 'include', the code works, but it does not save over to the df

the other one I tried doing was

```
new = df.loc[(df.date <= '2019-01-02') &
(df.date >= '2019-01-01')].loc[0].sample(100)
```

where I then just appended all the different dates together but was unsure how to then get the values which were not randomly selected back into the master of

Ideally, I think a loop would be the best option but cannot figure that out

```
for row in df:
    if df.loc[(df.date <= '2019-01-02') & (df.date >= '2019-01-01')].loc[0]:
        df.sample(n=100).replace(to_replace='no_include',value='include')
    elif df.loc[(df.date <= '2019-01-03') & (df.date >= '2019-01-02')].loc[0]:
        df.sample(n=50).replace(to_replace='no_include',value='include')
```

without getting the below error, I am really not sure what I am doing wrong for the loop, but I think this would be the best option

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better solution to this as I'm not sure how to replace without using the index, but I hope the below works for you.

We start by resetting the index and renaming the old index to 'index_'

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'index': 'index_'}, inplace=True)
```

this leaves us with:

```
    index_  date_       keep
0   0       2019-01-02  no_include
1   0       2019-01-02  no_include
2   0       2019-01-01  no_include
3   0       2019-01-01  no_include
4   1       2019-01-02  no_include
5   1       2019-01-01  no_include
```

We can then use the code you first tried and save the indexes that are sampled (i've only selected 2 due to my 6 row df)

```
selected = df[(df.date_ <= '2019-01-02') & (df.date_ >= '2019-01-01') & (df.index_ == 0)].sample(n=2).index
> Int64Index([3, 1], dtype='int64')
```

We can then loop over these, replace the 'keep' column in the original dataframe, and lastly reset the index.

```
for i in selected:
    df.at[i, 'keep'] = 'include'
df.set_index('index_', inplace=True)
```

which leaves us with...

```
       date_        keep
index_      
0      2019-01-02   no_include
0      2019-01-02   include
0      2019-01-01   no_include
0      2019-01-01   include
1      2019-01-02   no_include
1      2019-01-01   no_include
```

Does this yield the result that you're after?